# Google Chrome Devtools - not showing the first found result when searching for CSS selector

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

**Overview**

When I search for a CSS selector using the Chrome Devtools it does not highlight the first found result.

**How to reproduce it**

1. Go to any website, like [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/)
2. Press `F12`
3. Press `CTRL + F`
4. Search for `div[class]`
5. It highlights starting from the second element and forth, never the first one.

**Proof**
[image: Chrome devtools bug]

Anyone else is experiencing this? Any ideas how I could overcome this issue? Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear which div is selected from your screenshot. That being said, when I try in on W3Schools, it appears to select the first `div` element in the `DOM`. Have you tried in a incognito browser to make sure none of your extensions are interfering?

Comment: Exactly, that is the bug - it does not highlight the first div. I did try to deactivate all extension, try it on incognito, reset computer/browser, etc, no luck. I read that it was an old bug from version 74 if I'm not mistaken but apparently it is back for some users.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I misunderstood. I'm on Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit) and it works. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: It's a bug. It'll be fixed in the next update. Meanwhile add `,*` to the query and press Enter.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the heads up. So it would look like `div[class],*`? but won't this just select every single element instead?

Comment: This gave me a good idea though, doing something like `div[class],html[lang]` "fixed" the issue!

Comment: Your solution is correct whereas I incorrectly converted from xpath `|*` that selected `html`.

Comment: No problem! I'd like you to answer to it so I can choose your answer as a solution, please. :) `div[class],html:nth-child(1)` seems more foolproof though. (considering one may have shadow DOM activated and multiple `html`s can be selected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @wOxxOm for clarifying that this is a bug in Chrome.

A temporary solution is adding this to your query: `,html:nth-child(1)`

So, let's say you want to find all `div[class]`. Your final query would be: `div[class],html:nth-child(1)`.

This will make the bug focus on the `html` element and cancel the issue out.